# Reading multiple sheets - CSV - Using Java

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file with 5 sheets.
I want to read the second sheet.(Basically specify which sheet to read in my code).

Currently using CsvReader and CsvWriter java packages to read /write to a csv file. Which works great!!!

But is there anyway I can specify which sheet I want to read?

Anyone tried this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV file format does not support multiple sheets. You can save only only one sheet per file in CSV file format.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code to read excel file and you can loop for many sheet. But you must use plug-in jxl. Just download and import to lib. This my link can hlep you : http://www.mediafire.com/?fr1xkgdtx49awa8 .Sorry for bad english.

```
public List<Result> read(File inputWorkbook) throws IOException  {
    List<Result> list = new ArrayList<Result>();
    Workbook w;
    try {
        w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
        // Get the first sheet
        Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
        // Loop over first 10 column and lines
        for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) {
            Result rs= new Result(); 
            Cell cell0 = sheet.getCell(0, j);
            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) 
            {
                Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j);
                CellType type = cell.getType();
                if (cell.getType() == CellType.LABEL) {
                    System.out.println("I got a label " + cell.getContents());
                }

                if (cell.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) {
                    System.out.println("I got a number " + cell.getContents());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html) for opening an exel document and obtaining a specific sheet using

```
workbook.getSheet(sheetNumber);
```

Here's an [example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/examples/HSSFReadWrite.java) from apache on reading/writing excel